# Почему запрос и ответ идет 2 раза с axios?

Tags: reactjs

делаю запрос через axios и хочу сохранить данные в store redux.

```
export const loadAuthDate = async() => {
    let token = localStorage.getItem("auth-token")
    if(token === null) {
      token = ""
    }
    const tokenResponse = await axios.post('/api/user/tokenIsValid', null, {headers: {"x-auth-token": token} })
    if(tokenResponse.data){
      const userRes = await axios.get('/api/user/getUser ', {headers: {"x-auth-token": token, "id": tokenResponse.data.data._id},})
      console.log(userRes)
      return {
        type: LOAD_AUTH_DATE,
        token: token,
        user: userRes.data
      }
    }
}
```

Сам код на nodejs

```
const tokenIsValid = async(req,res) => {
  try {
    const token = req.header("x-auth-token");
    if(!token){
      return res.json(false)
    }
    const verified = jwt.verify(token, jwtSecret)
    if(!verified){
      return res.json(false)
    }
    const user = await User.findById(verified.id)
    if(!user){
      return res.json(false)
    }

    return res.status(200).json({data: user,})
  }
  catch (e) {
    return res.status(500).json({error: e.message})
  }
}
```

Вопрос, почему `console.log(userRes)` выводит у меня 2 раза , и если смотрю через network обращения к серверу действительно идет 2 раза. Это создает некоторые баги. Думал про useEffect но это не правильно использовать в redux

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: loadAuthDate вызывается дважды